# Outlook to SharePoint Calendar Autopopulate for Collaboration

Tags: calendar, outlook, synchronization, auto-populate

Im seeking a way to have multiple users Outlook calendars autopoulate to a collaborative calendar in SharePoint for weekly review in supervisors meeting.

So if Jim enters into his personal Outlook calendar that he will be taking leave on the 5th - 17th next month, it will show on his personal Outlook calendar and also show on the team's SharePoint calendar to be reviewed by multiple Supervisors for manning utilization. Rather than have Jim enter his info into his Outlook calendar, and also try to remember to send the info to the secretary for the secretary to input into SharePoint...

Answer (score 0):

A better solution to this issue is to create a shared SharePoint calendar for "Time Off" then have your users sync this calendar to their local outlook.  There is not away to sync calendar events from a personal outlook calendar to a SharePoint Calendar.